# What is faster/more efficient as target using in_array - array() or a variable with the array in it?

Tags: php, arrays

In short, which is more efficient or better or faster than the other?

```
if (in_array($value, array('val1', 'val2', 'val3'))  { ... }
```

or

```
$arr = array('val1', 'val2', 'val3');
if (in_array($value, $arr) { ... }
```

This code will run inside a **loop**, so the same `array(...)` declaration would happen multiple times.

Does it really matter if the array is in a variable or if it is redeclared on the fly for every `in_array` run inside a loop?

Comment: That kind of micro-optimization is both pointless and easily measured. Instead of asking, write a benchmark. You'll need a *lot* of iterations in order to find a measurable difference though.

Comment: While I do understand and appreciate the comment, I don't think the question deserves a downvote. If someone reading the question finds it to be a waste of time, they don't have to answer. However, for me who has an extreme deadline looming over my head, finding the answers below has been very helpful and saved a ton of time trying to benchmark this myself. Furthermore, Cheery's answer proves that this "micro-optimization" is NOT pointless when a lot of data is involved. I agree on the easily measured, but it's a matter of time spent trying to figure this out myself vs asking people who know.

Comment: Downvotes are for questions that show no research effort, or which are unclear or not useful. Your question is all three. You've done no research yourself, it's unclear what "more efficient or better or faster" means, and the answer is unlikely to be useful to anybody. The only thing Cheery's answer shows is that, as I said, this kind of micro-optimization is pointless. The real optimization came from choosing the better algorithm, not from a trivial change in assignment to a temporary variable.

Comment: Hm, you are right, I didn't follow my usual procedure of trying to figure this out on my own first... Please disregard my previous comment. However, it still saved me a lot of time for my project, so I don't regret posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking of speed - I prefer to use `isset($arr[$key])` for the keys of the associate array instead of `in_array` if it is possible.

```
$arraySize = 10000;
$loop = 10000;

// for numbers, at first
$array = range(1, $arraySize);
$start = getMtime();

for($i = 0; $i < $loop; $i++)
{
    if (in_array(rand(1, $arraySize), $array))
       continue;
}

$end = getMtime();
echo ($end - $start) . '<br>';

$start = getMtime();

for($i = 0; $i < $loop; $i++)
{
    if (isset($array[rand(1, $arraySize)]))
       continue;
}

$end = getMtime();
echo ($end - $start) . '<br>';

// the same, but for strings
foreach($array as &$el)
   $el = generateId(10);

$start = getMtime();

for($i = 0; $i < $loop; $i++)
{
    if (in_array(generateId(10), $array))
       continue;
}

$end = getMtime();
echo ($end - $start) . '<br>';

// now set them as keys
$array = array_flip($array);
echo 'Size of array ' . count($array) . '<br>';

$start = getMtime();

for($i = 0; $i < $loop; $i++)
{
    if (isset($array[generateId(10)]))
       continue;
}

$end = getMtime();
echo $end - $start;


function getMtime()
{
   $mtime = microtime(); 
   $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime); 
   $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0]; 
   return $mtime;
}  

function generateId($len = 10)
{
   return join('', array_map(function() { return substr('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', rand(0, 61), 1); }, range(1, $len)));
}
```

Results:

```
0.69922399520874  // in_array, numbers
0.0039558410644531 // isset, numbers
3.5183579921722 // in_array, strings
Size of array 10000
0.15712094306946  // isset, strings
```

No repeating keys, so the size of flipped array is the same. Of course, may be I'm missing something, but I do not expect high speed from in_array function.

Comment: I would never have thought of looking for something like `array_flip` to make `isset` possible to use... Thanks so much! This will save me a ton of time!

Answer (score 1):

The first way is faster, but not as legible. However, most arrays you need to evaluate this way are going to be arrays which you've already assigned to a variable for other purposes. The latter method requires an extra assignment, so it would take slightly more memory and time.

You should create or appropriate a time tracking class, if you care how fast things are (which is definitely a good way to approach programming). Almost every new method of doing things I create, I test the speed of it, and compare that to existing methods, to make sure it's beneficial/efficient and that I'm on the right track. Create a time class and execute each scenario you want to compare some 10000+ iterations, depending on what your testing, to see which is faster. That way you'll never have to guess or get somebody else's insight on the matter.

Edit:
This may not need to be said, but I thought I should add it just in case:
Any time class in php would need the ability to track milliseconds to be relevant.

Comment: In addition to testing in this way, different versions of PHP may give different performance results, so the first option may be faster in most versions of PHP, but slower in some

Comment: Good thing to consider.